# Was the miscalculation of number of souls by Terry intentional?

Tags: soul

In the Pixar animation *Soul* Terry explains number of souls per day, minute and second. but I think he calculated number of souls per minute wrongly. Was that intentional? If so Why?

Number of souls per day: 151000 (claimed)

Number of souls per minute: 105.2 (it must be 104.861111)

Number of souls per second: 1.75 (correct)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terry's answer is correct, as a "sidereal" day on Earth is actually 23 hours and 56 minutes - as such, 1,436 minutes, giving us an answer of 105.1532033426184 (or 105.2).

See [https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/days/en/#:~:text=On%20Earth%2C%20a%20sidereal%20day,23%20hours%20and%2056%20minutes](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/days/en/#:%7E:text=On%20Earth%2C%20a%20sidereal%20day,23%20hours%20and%2056%20minutes).